# PHP image grab when allow_url_fopen=off

Tags: php, wordpress, configuration, fopen, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am using thesis theme on my wordpress blog. I am hosting my blog at byethost which has **allow_url_fopen=Off** and **allow_url_include=Off**

In one of the function, code is trying to read an image url path. From what I understand, if *fopen* is *ON*, it will execute "if" case otherwise "else" case

```
  if ($thesis_design->image['fopen'])
     $image_path = $post_image['url'];
  else {
     $local_path = explode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $post_image['url']);
     $image_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $local_path[1];
  }
```

With this code, it is not able to grab the image if I provide absolute path (i.e. http://brijux.com/images/example.jpg) but it can grab image with relative path (i.e images/example.jpg)

But if I comment out "if" case and use only the "else" case, it can grab image with the absolute path.

So my question is,

1. if **allow_url_fopen=Off**, shouldn't it only execute the "else" part?
2. how does it grab image file if I am only providing relative path in the "if" case?

Answer (score 0):

If you use fopen and provide a relative path it treats the image as a local file.  If you provide the 'absolute' path i.e. the URL then it goes through the loopback interface and grabs it like it's on the web.

Comment: I am new to PHP so please bare with me. what does "$thesis_design->image['fopen']" check for the condition? What does it do if my host does not support fopen?

Comment: I'm not sure what it would do.  I'm not familiar with your object.  You can use some print statements to learn a little bit more about it, though.  Try: var_dump($thesis_design); to see what all is in there.

Comment: It looks like $thesis_design->image['fopen'] is simply an array value that COULD be set elsewhere in the code. It is not guaranteed to be a check for the server capabilities. See if you can find in the code where the image array is generated.